# $E$ is closed $\iff\partial E$ (boundary of set $E$) $\subseteq E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am studying topology of euclidean space from William Wade's text book.

I saw this question. But I cannot come up with any ideas.

Please show me the solution in an instructive an clear way.

Thank you for yourhelp.

$E$ is closed $\iff\partial E$ (boundary of set $E$) $\subseteq E$

[image]

Comment: How do you define $E$ to be closed? If you define the closure of $E$ to be $\overline E=E\cup\partial E$, and if you have either proven or defined that a set is closed if $\overline {E}=E$; then the conclusion is immediate.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Now you show the first part of the proof. Is ıt right? @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Sorry, I know I dont want such thing. But, please can you show me this more teachable below answer part? I want to learn. Please:) @PeterTamaroff

Comment: @B11b, the question is what definition of "closed" did you learn? There are several equivalent definitions.

Comment: @B11b As Yoni says, we need to know how you define a set to be closed, or what theorems you can use. Depending on that, the proof can be more or less contorted.

Comment: Different classes and different books use different definitions and theorems for the meaning of "closed".  Many classes use the definition "a set is closed if all its limit points are in the set" in which case this is simply part of the definition.  Other classes use the definition "a set is closed if its complement is open" in which case there is a lot here to prove.  We need to know i) how closed was defined ii) how d(E) is defined and iii) what theorems you have so far.  In *your* class.  It will be different for other classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove (if you haven't already) that a set is closed $\iff E=\overline E$.

Since $\partial E=\overline{E}\cap\overline{E^c}\subseteq \overline E=E$, the result follows. On the other hand, note (prove it) that $\overline E=E\cup \partial E$, so if $\partial E\subseteq E$, $E=\overline E$, so $E$ is closed.

**ADD** Given a set $E$ on a space $(X,\mathscr T)$, one can define the closure of a set to be the intersection of all closed sets that contain $E$, that is $$\overline E=\bigcap\{F\subseteq X:E\subset F\text{ and } F \text{ is closed}\}$$

That is why we usually say $\overline E$ is the smallest set (w.r.t. inclusion) that contains $E$. Because $\overline E$ is the intersection of closed sets, it is closed. Thus, if $E=\overline E$, $E$ is seen to be closed. On the other hand, if $E$ is closed, $E$ *itself* is a closed set containing $E$, so $\overline E\subseteq E$. Since by definition, we always have $E\subseteq\overline E$, it follows $E=\overline E$.

Comment: Now, I have comprehended all thing. I tired to realized in my mind. But something was not clarified. This addition helps:)  Thank you for addition:)

Comment: Sorry, I stack with a point. $\parital E =$$ E^{\overline}$ \$E^o$ $=E^{\overline}\cap(E^{o})^{c}$ Is this writing is false?

Comment: @B11b Could you rewrite that? You want `\overline{E}`

Comment: Sorry I write a few minitue

Comment: So sorry. I dont know to write latex enough and fast. So I added a picture above :)

Comment: @B11b =) Remember that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ for any sets $A,B$.

Comment: Okay I see. Well, then, my expansion is false.

Comment: @B11b No, it is correct! $\overline{E}\cap \overline{E^c}\subseteq \overline E$ is correct-.

Comment: Okay. I got. Thank you for help:)

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is a boundary point if every its neighborhood intersect both $E$ and $X\setminus E$.

If $E$ is closed, its complement $F=X\setminus E$ is open and every point $x\in F$ has a neighborhood contained in $F$, i.e. no points in $F$ are boundary points of $E$.

The other way around. If $\partial E\subseteq E$ then every point $x\in F$ is not boundary, i.e. it has a neighborhood that does not intersect either $E$ or $F$. But since $x\in F$, the neighborhood does not intersect $E$, and therefore, $F$ is open, $E$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\partial E=\overline E \cap \overline{X-A}$ and $\partial E⊆\overline E$. and $$ E \text{ is closed} \iff E=\overline E $$

Comment: `\bar` seems to work fine on small stuff, but `\overline` is better for bigger entries-.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Useful results}:$ Without any notion of metric spaces, the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed from the fact that the arbitrary reunion of open sets is open.

Indeed, for any collection of open sets $\{\mathcal O_j \}_{j\in A},\:$whenever $\:\alpha\in \mathcal O_{j^*},\:$an element of any indexed set from the arbitrary collection, we know that $\:\alpha\in\mathcal O,\:$the union, because $\mathcal O_{j^*}\:$being open means that $$\forall\alpha\in\mathcal O_{j^*}\:\exists\delta^*_{>0}\:\:\text{s.t.}\underbrace{\:(\alpha-\delta^*,\alpha+\delta^*)}_{\large \mathcal N_{\delta^*}\normalsize (\alpha)}\subset \mathcal O_{j^*}\subset \mathcal O.$$

$\implies \bigcup_{j\in A}\mathcal O_j =\mathcal O\:\:$is open $\iff \bigcap_{j\in A}\mathcal O_j^c=\mathcal O^c\:\:$is closed, by De Morgan's laws.

Another thing is that $\:(\partial E \cup \text{int}(E))\subset\overline E \implies\partial E\subset E.$

Indeed, if $\:\beta\in\left(\partial E \cup \text{int}(E)\right),\:$then either $\:\beta\in\text{int}(E)\subset E\subset \overline E\:$ or $\:\beta\in\partial E\:$ but that's it since $\:$ $(\partial E \cap \text{int}(E))=\emptyset.$

Now, $\:\beta\in \partial E\implies(\forall \delta_{>0}\:\exists\mathcal N_\delta\small(\beta)\normalsize \cap E^c\neq\emptyset\:\land\: \forall \delta_{>0}\:\exists\mathcal N_\delta\small(\beta)\normalsize \cap E\neq\emptyset),\:$ which is more restrictive than $\:\:\beta \in \overline E\implies \: (\forall \delta_{>0}\:\exists\mathcal N_\delta\small(\beta)\normalsize \cap E\neq\emptyset)$

That's why $\:\partial E\subset \overline E$